# Jacobian of three functions

Tags: calculus, jacobian

If $$F=xu+v-y$$ $$G=u^2+\cos y+ w$$ $$H=zu-v+vw$$ the question is to find the Jacobian of $(F,G,H)$ wrt $(u,v,w)$

I am aware of the determinant expression for the Jacobian.But couldn't apply here since here the functions involve product of variables as well.Any idea on how to solve these type of problem shall be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You can still differentiate products of functions i.e $F_{u} = x, G_{u} = 2u, H_{w} = v$ etc. So you just need to compute $F_{u}, F_{v}, F_{w}, G_{u}, G_{v}, \dots$ and put them in the matrix form you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a differentiable mapping

$$ f \, : \, U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{R}^3 $$

such that, for all $(u,v,w) \in U$ :

$$ f(u,v,w) = \big( F(u,v,w), G(u,v,w), H(u,v,w) \big). $$

$F$, $G$ or $H$ are real-valued coordinate functions. 
The Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $x_0 = (u_0, v_0, w_0) \in U$ is defined as :

$$ \mathrm{Jac}(f,x_0) = \begin{bmatrix} \displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(x_0) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(x_0) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial w}(x_0) \\[2mm] \displaystyle \frac{\partial G}{\partial u}(x_0) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}(x_0) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial G}{\partial w}(x_0) \\[2mm] \displaystyle \frac{\partial H}{\partial u}(x_0) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial H}{\partial v}(x_0) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial H}{\partial w}(x_0) \end{bmatrix} $$

In your case, with $F(u,v,w) = xu + v - y$, $G(u,v,w) = u^2 + \cos(y) + w$ and $H(u,v,w) = zu - v + vw$, you obtain:

$$ \mathrm{Jac}(f,x_0) = \begin{bmatrix} x & 1 & 0 \\ 2u_0 & 0 & 1 \\ z & w_0 - 1 &  v_0 \end{bmatrix}. $$